# Enabling Angular.js after the page has loaded

Tags: angularjs

I am in the process of building a AJAX driven search application. It will essentially be a single page app. So I have been evaluating different frameworks for this, like Backbone and Angular.js.

At the moment Angular.js is the winner but I have a few issues that I am trying to get around. The main problem I have is that I very much want to have the first page load of my app to be rendered server side and then all interactions to be handled by Angular.js. My reason for this is because I don't want a user to experience that double wait.

So essentially my plan is to load data in my `ng-view` `div` on the server side. Then update that content via Angular.js AJAX for all changes the user makes after that.

My difficulty is how do I prevent Angular.js from looking at the URL on the first page load and doing it's thing and then rendering the content?

Comment: Do you have some code to show ? Do you bootstrap the app manually or automatically ? First guess to your problem is to manually bootstrap the Angular app when the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ng-view without having Angular modifying the DOM container. An alternative would be to use a directive and read your own $routeParams and then manipulate the DOM.

There seems to be something inherently wrong with having to "enable Angular after the page has loaded" to prevent Angular from doing its work.

Instead of loading the data into your template on the server, why not fetch this in the controller of your current route? Yes the data will be loaded in a separate request, but the user will not have to "double wait".

I would create a route like the following:

```
app = angular.module('Main', [])
        .config( ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
            $routeProvider
                .when('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: '/partial/dashboard'
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'})
        )
```

And then in the controller:

```
@DashboardCtrl = ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route) ->
    # Fetch all data to populate the dashboard template here.
    $http(
        method: "GET"
        url: "/api/dashboard"
        data: $scope.request
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
        $scope.dashboard_data = data
    ).error (data, status, headers, config) ->
        console.log data
```

Surely that is easier than having to worry about rendering data into your template both server and client side?